# MVC attribute routing and CustomError pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, custom-error-handling

What is the best way of implementing 404 (for example) error pages in MVC 5 with attribute routing?

I've read this article: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

And it seems a bit far fetched for a simple 404 redirect!!

I have a controller called Notify:

```
[RoutePrefix("notify")]
public class NotifyController : Controller
{
    [Route("not-found")] 
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/notify/error" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/notify/not-found"/>
</customErrors>
```

If i enter a dodgy URL, i get the not-found page like so:
https://www.mydomain.co.uk/notify/not-found?aspxerrorpath=/lkl

The article I linked to suggests adding the following to CustomErrors to remove the aspxerrorpath:

```
redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"
```

However this breaks the redirect.  So if I leave it out, it still redirects but doesn't return a 404 status.  So I changed my ActionResult to this:

```
[Route("not-found")] 
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    if (Response.StatusCode == 200)
            Response.StatusCode = 404; 
        return View();
}
```

This threw a 404 status code, but gave me the default 404 error page!

Is there a recommended approach to handling CustomErrors in MVC using attribute routing?  Or do I need to faff around with aspx pages like in the link?

Comment: what is so `far fetched` about it? Seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: 'far fetched' as in previously (in web forms) I would simply point the CustomErrors page to an aspx page and voila.  Now, I can't point the CustomErrors page to one of my routed views.  Instead I have to create an aspx (and add a response for the status code) and a html page, add a httpErrors section to web.config etc.  You don't think that's a bit far fetched?

Comment: I think the article I linked to complements this one quite well: https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging